# Unexplainable RDP slowdown

Tags: performance, remote-desktop

I have a really weird problem that I can't wrap my head around.

Situation:
RDP server, running Windows Server 2019, with many clients.
A user connects to the RDP server from Windows 10.

They open a browser to use google maps.
They start Teamviewer so I can view what they see inside the RDP session.
They enter a place to make google maps view it. I see it quick, they see it slow. They perform 2 more searches or perform planning a route and 3rd or 4th time for them it freezes, while I can see all normally.

They exit the RDP session and reconnect (no logout) and they get the update and cycle repeats.

With teamviewer closed in their session, They open teamviewer on the local computer so I can view there.
I see the same slow downs and crashes as they do, and reopening the RDP connection fixes it.

If I open a browser locally and do the same, everything works fast.

They have an Intel HD Graphics 4400. I updated the drivers from 20.19.15.5129 to 20.19.15.5144 but that didn't help. In the drivers, I've set 3D performance to high, was balanced, and that only gave a marginal improvement.

If I connect to that same RDP session from a different computer, the problem does not exist, so something in this computer is not working correctly, but only when RDP is involved.

Any ideas what this can be?

Comment: (1) I would check their RDP connection parameters, and especially the Experience tab. (2) Also their network connection and driver. (3) Their Event Viewer might have something relevant. (4) Is their RDP version same as yours? (5) I wonder if the Windows Server has enabled Remote Desktop Protocol data compression ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/remote-desktop/session-hosts)).

Comment: @harrymc The RDP files are generated by script across all workstations, so they are the same. I did play with the experience tab setting a lower bitrate to see if its a hardware accelleration issue, but no dice. Network connection and driver seems not to be the issue, given that running everything locally is no issue at all, and I would expect an issue there. So far it all seems graphics related somehow, but I'll do some testing, just to be sure.

Comment: @harrymc Didn't see anything in the event viewer though. RDP version is the same. 5: now that could be something although it would somehow be different for just one client, but I'll look into that.

Comment: For display, you could if you have access perhaps pop in a stronger GPU and see if this helps. I was thinking more about the network when I suggested 5.